# Opencart Marketing Campaign is not tracking number of orders

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I have created a marketing campaign in the Opencart (from Marketing/Marketing/add Champain) and I have used the URL correctly to order a product. but it seems only track the number of clicks, and it's not tracking number of ordered products, using the tracking ID in the URL. How to enable ordered product tracking using this marketing campaign?

there is same questions without any answer:
[here](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=161553) and [here](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&t=150298)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you have an order in Sales/Orders, you should change the status to "Completed" at end. if you set the status to something else, it will not count into the campaign!!

seems it's a bug!